# Using Spatial Join tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join

I have a map with two layers: one of polygons and one of points (in coordinate pairs). To each point, I would like to match the attributes of the polygon in which it is located (or closest to). I am trying to use the Spatial Join tool. In the Target Features I have put in the points layer and in the Join Features I have put in the polygons layer.

The resulting layer has the coordinates, but unfortunately all attributes are `<null>`. Any idea why this is happening and how I can get the resulting layer to include the attributes as required?

Here are some screenshots to help understand the problem:
The layer of points and layer of polygons are:
[image]

And the resulting layer, after using the Spatial Join Tool as indicated above is:
[image]

Comment: First, your screenshots only show polygons so I have to ask, are you sure the features intersect? What is your join type (intersect, within, nearest..., etc). Are your data in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Have you gone ahead and exported a shapefile out of your .csv Events layer yet? When adding XY data ArcMap creates a spatial data table that does not have an ObjectID, and so cannot perform certain tasks.

Comment: Do you know if it automatically matches to the closest polygon if a point is not in any of the polygons?

Comment: You must enter a Search Radius (optional) to match points that do not overlap Polygons.

Comment: Thanks @klewis, but what if I specify a radius such that there is a point which can be matched to two or more polygons? Does it automatically match to the nearest one?

Comment: It automatically picks the closest one if you set the match option to "CLOSEST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to export the data by clicking the .csv layer, Data, and then Export Data. Name the file a .`.shp` file. Then do the join operation using the Spatial Join Tool using the polygons and the shape file of coordinates. Then it all works out.